# Visual Studio F5 debugging is slower than Attach to Process

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

If i start my application with F5 (debugging) it takes for a certain operation about 2000ms. If i start the application with F5 + CTRL (without debugging) and attach Visual Studio with "Attach to Process" it takes only ~100ms.

Has someone a idea what component can cause this performance 'problem'?

C# application / VS 2012.

**Edit**

Code-Snipped:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
changed.Validate(context);
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Are you triggering the operation yourself? How do you start it?

Comment: Simple by clicking on a button.

Comment: It is normal and to be expected that things are slower when the debugger is attached. Normally the application is meant to be used without a debugger attached, so "performance" is measured without it. Is this a problem? I know some huge applications that can be annoying to debug because they become extremely slow when the debugger is attached.

Comment: It first place is annoying. 
But I do not understand whats the different between F5 (debugging) and "Attach to process" both attaches the debugger but the first one is 2000% slower.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?  Express? Pro? Ultimate?

Comment: But attach to process IS attaching the debugger. It's just that F5 is doing something differently but what?!

Answer (score 1):

One major thing that makes lot of difference is during F5 or debugging visual studio loads all the pdb files.pdb files are the program database files and are the reason why you are able to debug.If you compile in build mode you will see the bin folder having .pdb file corresponding to every dll.

More on pdb files : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(vs.71).aspx

one article on this topic
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/01/start-debugging-vs-start-without-debugging-vstipdebug0037.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I saw this article. But the load of the pdb's should only impact during the first load of them ?
"Attach to process" loads the dps pdb also. => should impact in the same way as F5.

Comment: It's not just the startup time though. When starting with F5 I get 20% sustained CPU usage and with Attach to process it is zero. This is for a .NET Framework app running in IIS when I'm not even hitting the server. If I run the app then it stops at breakpoints whichever way I run it. It's really bad!